# How can I implement Calendar in My Application ?

Tags: android

I have tried a lot but I didn't get any success yet, how can I call or **implement Calendar in Android Application**.

In my emulator there is one App Name Calendar Pad, which I downloaded from Android market.

***Can I Call Calendar Pad through my Application, if yes, how?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such CalendarView views in Android, so if you need to have a copy of the calendar inside your app - you must create a layout yourself. Calendar data such as events can be accessed via ContentProviders: [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Hope this helps.